# Cisco Aironet 1200 dhcp relay config

Tags: cisco, wifi, ios

It's about 6 years since I last configured an IOS device and I have forgot a lot of it sadly!

I got a Cisco Aironet 1200 AP ( IOS (tm) C1200 Software (C1200-K9W7-M), Version 12.3(2)JA2, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1) ) which I want fo configure in either one of two ways...

1. Have it relay the signals from my wireless TP-Link router so that the signals can reach out to my garden.
2. Configure it with as a normal AP, using WPA or WPA2 without radius and relaying DHCP from the TP-Link router.

I tried configuring it as preferred first alternative, but could not figure out how to do it.

I then tried alternative 2, but I don't remember how to set up dhcp relay.

Could someone please help me by pointing me to a working example to any of the two alternatives above?

Thanks in advance!
/Rickard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring DHCP Relay is done through the ip helper-address command in interface config mode, like so :

```
interface ethernet 1
    ip helper-address 192.168.1.1
```

where 192.168.1.1 is your DHCP server.